# In the sitemap module magento, sitemap.xml generated when the front of the product categories do not want to add the path how to do that?

Tags: magento, sitemap

Who can tell me, in magento module in the sitemap, sitemap.xml generated when the front of the product categories do not want to add the path, for example: the product page address is http://XXXX.com/category/category_product.html, I want to Product page address to http://XXXX.com/category_product.html, how to do that? Who can give me a good suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what's being asked here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve that by enabling canonical url for products in `System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimizations -> Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products -> Yes`